# Require Ext JS class with a relative name

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to require a class using a relative path in Ext JS? Suppose I have a directory structure like this:

```
appRoot
`- some
   `- really
      `- long
         `- path
            |- MyClass.js
            `- MyClassDependency.js
```

And `MyClass.js` looks like this:

```
Ext.define('RootName.some.really.long.path.MyClass', {
    requires: ['RootName.some.really.long.path.MyClassDependency'],
    // Snipped.
});
```

And `MyClassDependency.js` is like this:

```
Ext.define('RootName.some.really.long.path.MyClassDependency', {
    // Snipped.
});
```

Is there a way to express this dependency without referencing the whole class name? I would like to, for example, move the folder that `MyClass.js` and `MyClassDependency.js` are in without having to update every single dependency that `MyClass.js` has.

Answer (score 0):

Until now there is no standard way to do so.
In theory, it would be possible to overwrite the method `Ext.ClassManager.define` to prepend the current "namespace" to the classes in the `requires` array.

```
Ext.override(Ext.ClassManager, {
  define : function(className, data) {
    //prepend data.requires with className
    this.callSuper(arguments);
  }
});
```

Doing so, Sencha Cmd would no longer be able to build a minified version of your app since it can't any longer resolve the requirements, as long as you do not include all files in the build anyway.
I would not make this attempt, since the risk you break something with an ExtJs update is huge.

---

Another way you can go is, to use wildcards.

```
Ext.define('TestApp.view.Main', {
  requires: [
    'TestApp.view.*'
  ]
});
```

---

The last thing comes to my mind is to use the alias.

```
Ext.define('TestApp.view.MainDep', {
  alias: ['module1.mainDep']
});

Ext.define('TestApp.view.Main', {
  requires: [
    'module1.mainDep',
    'module2.*',
  ]
});
```